# PHP: Symlink in public_html cannot be accessed through browser

Tags: apache-2.2, symlink

I have tester.php file which I want to run on the browser and I have created symlink to it in my public_html folder, but still when I try to run it, its not working and gives me following error message.

```
Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 403
web.upc03.dev.com
Sun Apr 4 22:41:23 2010
Apache
```

I am not sure as to why am I getting this error message, I have check all file permissions settings and it seems to be fine.

My File permissions settings are:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  for tester.php
```

Is there something that should be done other way or is this not the proper approach ?

Answer (score 1):

The `FollowSymlinks` [option](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options) needs to be enabled for that location/directory.

Comment: How can this be enabled. Actually we just changed our development server and I just did `scp` to copy all files and folder from one dev server to another dev server. Is there any internal settings which needs to be set for the implementations. Would really appreciate if you can provide some details as am not sure how to activate it.

Comment: rachel it isn't php internal setting but apache's settings, check apache conf.